# Appropriate logic for this program

Tags: c, if-statement, logic

The program says to read a file containing an unknown amount of numbers. Each number is one of the numbers 1 to 9. A number can appear zero or more times and can appear anywhere in the file. The number 0 ends the data. 
Sample of data:

```
5 3 7 7 7 4 3 3 2 2 2 6 7 4 7 7 2 2 9 6 6 6 6 6 8 5 5 3 7 9 9 9 0
```

The program should read the data once and print the number which appears the most in consecutive positions and the number of times it appears. Ignoring the possibilty of a tie.

It should print: the number 6 appears 5 times.

This is my sketchy logic so far:

```
  scan for num
  while num is not zero
  store the num into num2 (another variable)
  scan for another variable
  compare and check if num is equal to num2
  if it is increment count variable (numCount)
  declare another count variable (numCount2) and initialize it to 0
  check if numCount > numCount2 and 
  store the value of previous count variable into numCount2
  ....
```

Am i doing fine?

Comment: You can divide that task into two parts. Write a function that scans equal numbers and returns that number and how many times it appeared. For the sample data it would return 5,1 3,1 7,3 etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is messy because you are scanning the number for the while loop, and then again inside the loop. I would do it like this:

```
max_num = 0
max_count = 0
previous_num = 0
previous_count = 0

while read into num (stops when zero)
  if num equals previous_num
    increment previous_count
  else
    if previous_count > max_count
      max_count = previous_count
      max_num = previous_num
    previous_num = num
    previous_count = 0
if previous_count > max_count
  max_count = previous_count
```

Comment: After the last number is read, you need to check (outside the loop) whether `previous_count` is larger than `max_count` and update `max_num` if it is.